# mgo time.Time or boolean check

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a mongo document which contains a date field which can also be false (or not defined), and I can't seem to find how to check if the field is available OR is false OR is a date (time.Time) in golang/mgo :S

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? Do you want to query all the documents where "the field is available OR is false OR is a date (time.Time)" or you have retrieved this document and want to check the value in the map (bson.M)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `time.Time` field, and want to know whether it was properly set with a valid date, you can query its `IsZero()` method. Otherwise, if you're trying to query the database for such a document, you can do one of the following.

Query if the field is false:

```
iter := collection.Find(bson.M{"field": false}).Iter()
```

Query if the field is available, with the [$exists operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/):

```
iter := collection.Find(bson.M{"field": bson.M{"$exists": true}}).Iter()
```

Query if the field is a date, using the [$type operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/):

```
iter := collection.Find(bson.M{"field": bson.M{"$type": 9}}).Iter()
```

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I needed. I already knew about the type operator in mongo, but I did not find the IsZero() method yet, and that does exactly what I needed!