# Check object value exist in mongodb document in golang using mgo package

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I need to check that **object with FIELD value X** already exists in mongo db using mgo package in golang. I already use $exists, that will find objects with FIELD no matter what its value. But I only need to know that object already is in db with value using **mgo package in golang**.

I also use `db.collection.count({id=0})` in mongo shell. it give a boolean value as what i expected. but there is no method in **mgo package(golang)**. i want to know that representation using mgo package.

```
"dbconfigs": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "default": true,
      "widgets": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "position": 1,
          "type": 1,
          "class": "normal green",
          "metric": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Total Downloads",
            "category": "Usage Analytics",
            "type": 1,
            "api": "url2",
            "templateurl": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "position": 2,
          "type": 1,
          "class": "normal red",
          "metric": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Total Uploads",
            "category": "Usage Analytics",
            "type": 1,
            "api": "url1",
            "templateurl": ""
          }
        }
]
}]
```

according to the above example i want know wheather dbconfigs --> id = 0 is already exists or not as a boolean value.

Comment: i did go trough that question. but it is not give solution.

Comment: db.collection.count({id=0}) this is only mongo shell command..I want to know do it using mgo package in golang.

Comment: That is the answer to your question as the *count* you use, didn't provide a boolean value, just an integer as a sum of records that match the condition. If your issue, from here, is just the go syntax have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721801/mgo-time-time-or-boolean-check

Comment: do you mean *collection.Find(bson.M{"id": 0}).Count()* ?

Comment: is that work? please wait for check it. thank you.

Comment: it is works. thank you for support.